# IntelliJ IDEA removing Gradle modules automatically after re-opening / re-starting project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, module

I have added existing Gradle module in my maven project. After setup it works perfectly fine. When I re-open projects for the second time or re-start IntelliJ IDEA it kicks off my that specific module from the side bar. Any solid reason?

Regards

Comment: Is it possible to provide project examples and exact steps to reproduce? I tried with Maven and Gradle projects on my machine and nothing is removed.

Comment: I am adding a gradle module in Intellij through following: New, Module with Existing Resources, selecting Gradle option, and just go next next. And it imports and builds fine. But when I re-open intellij. This specific module is lost. Then I re-add through the same procedure.

Comment: I followed the same steps, but couldn't reproduce the issue. Could you please attach screenshot of project tree after adding Gradle module?

Comment: Thanks y.bedrov. I am able to resolve it just by turning on the view option for gradle module.